# django-social-auth backend not found

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-socialauth

I'm trying to add authentication with Twitter, GitHub, Google and Facebook using `django-social-auth`, and the backends I expect to be there are not available.

Installed it according to manual:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.github.GithubBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuthBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2Backend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleBackend',
    # ....unnecessary backends

    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY         = ''
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET      = ''
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = ''
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = ''
GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY          = ''
GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET       = ''
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID      = ''
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET  = ''

LOGIN_URL          = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL    = '/login/'

SOCIAL_AUTH_FORCE_POST_DISCONNECT = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION = ['next',]
```

Added URLs in template: `{% url socialauth_begin 'twitter' %}, {% url socialauth_begin 'github' %} etc`, all fine until here.

But when I click the link - it gives me error: `Incorrect authentication service "twitter"`

As per manual I've checked contents of `social_auth.backends.BACKENDS` and it has only this: `{'openid': <class 'social_auth.backends.OpenIdAuth'>}`

Why backends I've enabled are not there and why there is a backend that I've actually not enabled?

PS: python 2.7.3, django 1.4.5, django-social-auth 0.7.19

Comment: Are you sure? https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/social_auth/backends/twitter.py

Comment: Have you check the error documentation of twitter about this `Incorrect authentication service "twitter"`. In that documentation, it stated the meaning of that error

Comment: Checked here http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#exceptions
All it says is: `WrongBackend - Raised when the backend given in the URLs is invalid (not enabled or registered)`.
AFAIK it's both registered and enabled.

Comment: It means the url send by the backend is invalid, it's not backend not found. Have you complete the requirements? Have you create an app in twitter and get the key? You must put that key in your settings.

Comment: Me ashamed. True, it needs twitter KEY a SECRET to be filled in, and then it works. But damn, why it gives so unobvious and misleading error message then?
Anyway, question answered, I guess other backends have same problem.

Answer (score 6):

If somebody will bump into this error message same silly way as I did. 
You just need the KEY and SECRET from the auth provider, twitter, google etc. It doesn't say a thing about that in the error message, but that's why it's failing.

Comment: It clearly says in the [docs](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/twitter.html), you need to fill the consumer key and secret.

Comment: Obviously it needs these two be filled in to operate. But it's not said anywhere that filling in these values operates like a enable/disable switch for the whole Twitter backend, and this is not obvious by itself as for me.